# Is there a way to add a new column beside 'timestamp' in Python?

Tags: python, dataframe, timestamp

I try to convert 'timestamp' into something like 'yyyy-mm-dd' and make a new column called 'date_time', please show me how to do this. Thank you.

I only know how to do it each by each, for example:

```
from datetime import datetime

t = 1598046140

datetime.fromtimestamp(t).isoformat()
```

====> the output is '2020-08-22T07:42:20'

Like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/6xOtr.png

Comment: I didnt get that new column part but does this help you? datetime.fromtimestamp(t).date()

Comment: As @Karthik said `datetime.fromtimestamp(t).date().isoformat()` works. Output: `'2020-08-22'`

Comment: Thank you.  Is there a way to generate a new column without manually put each timestamp inside the code and run? There are about 200 timestamps in the data, I hope to generate a new column that contains the converted time (will also be 200 rows)

Comment: I add a picture to explain what I mean, could anyone please help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your dataframe is `df`

```
df["date_time"] = df["timestamp"].apply(lambda x: datetime.fromtimestamp(x).date().isoformat())
```